# Growth of $f'(x)$ for $x$ large enough and monotonicity of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, asymptotics, monotone-functions

If we have as $x\to \infty$, $$f'(x)=-g(x)+O\left( x^{-3}\right)$$ where $g(x)> 0$ for all $x$ and $g(x)=O(x^{-2})$ for $x$ large.

> Prove that $f$ is decreasing for $x$ large enough.

So by definition og Big O there exists $M>0$ and $x_0$ such that for all $x>x_0$, $$f'(x)\leq -g(x)+\frac{M}{x^3} $$
Now since $g(x)=O(x^{-2})$ so can we choose $x$ large enough such that $-g(x)+\frac{M}{x^3}\leq 0  $ ?

I would request a counterexample or a proof ofthe above question.

Comment: loosely speaking for $x$ large enough the $1/x^2$ will dominate, meaning the error term becomes effectively negligible. Thus $f'(x)$ is negative for large enough $x$.

Comment: @JustWandering Please see the edited question. Is the result also true now?

Comment: The result should still be true for the same reason

Comment: @JustWandering Please write a proof. It is a request. I will accept it

Comment: @JustWandering Take $g$ defined by $g(x) = 1/x^2$. It satisfies the hypotheses, yet $f'(x) > 0$ for large $x$.

Comment: @ClementC. No it doesn't? you are -g(x) right?

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I must be needing glasses, I... missed the minus sign.

Comment: @ClementC. No worries Clement, I think my initial statement is true and I couldnt really think of anything else (like counterexample)

Comment: @Tom I don't think I have much else to add from my very first comment though. I can try to formalise it but I dont think I can add much else

Comment: @Tom Please see my comment above, it is quite tough to write a rigorous (analysis-oriented) proof for me anyways, I dont have much else to say other the first comment I made

Comment: @JustWandering Thanks.

Comment: Since $g\ge0$, you don’t need any asymptotics for $g$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you. Can you please write a brief proof as an answer ? I will with utmost respect accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=- \frac{3}{16} \frac{1}{x^2}+O\left( x^{-3}\right) -g(x)\\
= -  \frac{1}{x^2}\left[\frac{3}{16}+O(x{^-1})\right] -g(x) \tag 1$$

Now, $g(x) = O(x{^-1}) \implies  g(x) \to 0$, hence for $x$ large enough, the factor inside square brackets is always strictly positive.

Also, $g(x) \ge 0$. Hence $f'(x)<0$ for $x$ large enough, and in that range $f(x)$ is monotonous (decreasing).

Edit: $g(x) = O(x{^-1})$ implies that that there exists some $C>0$ and some $x_0$ such that $|g(x)| \le C x^{-1}$ for all $x>x_0$ . Then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} |g(x)| \le \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{C}{x} = 0$$

which implies $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 0$

Comment: Thank you. How do we get that $g(x)=O(x^{-1})$ implies $g(x)\to 0$?

Comment: Answered in edit

Comment: But then why can't we write since $h(x)=O(x^{-3})$, so $h(x)\to 0$? Also the first factor of $-\frac{1}{x^2}\left[\frac{3}{16}+O(x^{-1})\right]$ which is $\frac{1}{x^2}$ also goes to $0$ as $x\to \infty$.